# What steps can I take to fix a StackExchange.Redis timeout error with the HMGET command on Azure Redis cache?

Tags: azure-redis-cache

> {"Message":"Timeout awaiting response (outbound=0KiB, inbound=0KiB, 5996ms elapsed, timeout is 5000ms), command=HMGET, next: HMGET MasterMYS_PrivilegeMaster, inst: 0, qu: 0, qs: 3, aw: False, rs: ReadAsync, ws: Idle, in: 334900, serverEndpoint: dev-mcare21-redis.redis.cache.windows.net:6380, mc: 1/1/0, mgr: 10 of 10 available, clientName: mcare21-masterapi-74db56444c-hbm7d, IOCP: (Busy=0,Free=1000,Min=2,Max=1000), WORKER: (Busy=11,Free=32756,Min=2,Max=32767), v: 2.2.4.27433 (Please take a look at this article for some common client-side issues that can cause timeouts:

[image]

Comment: where are running HMGET command

Comment: will give you sample steps on how to avoid it.

Answer (score 0):

> I've referred to this for Azure Cache for [Redis](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/cache-overview) and git @[eerhardt](https://github.com/StackExchange/StackExchange.Redis).

[image]

The connection to the Redis server timed out, according to the error message. This could be caused by a number of things, such as network issues or incorrect connection settings. You might try the following to solve the issue:

- Check to see if your network can reach and use the Redis server.
- Verify the connection string's accuracy and ensure it contains the right credentials.
- Boost the timeout setting for the connection.
- Try logging on to the Redis server from a different network or machine to see if the problem is specific to your current setup.
- Examine the firewall settings to confirm that the Redis server may be accessed from your network.

**Code:**

```cs
try
    {
                
     string redisConnectionString = "connectionstring";
       var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);
       var redisDatabase = redisConnection.GetDatabase();
       RedisKey key = "key1";
      RedisValue[] fields = new RedisValue[] { "field1", "field2", "field3" };
      RedisValue[] values = redisDatabase.HashGet(key, fields);
    if (values != null)
                {
                    foreach (var value in values)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine($"Retrieved value: {value}");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Failed to retrieve values.");
                }
                redisConnection.Dispose();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
               
          }
```

**Output:**

[image]

**In Azure Redis:**

[image]

**To Set Values:**

```cs
 try
   {
      string redisConnectionString = "connectionstring";
      var redisConnection = ConnectionMultiplexer.Connect(redisConnectionString);
      var redisDatabase = redisConnection.GetDatabase();
      RedisKey key = "key1";
      RedisValue[] fields = { "field1", "field2", "field3" };
      redisDatabase.HashSet(key, new[] { new HashEntry("field1", "866 13.90.202.154:13000"), new HashEntry("field2", "866 13.90.202.154:13000"), new HashEntry("field3", "866 13.90.202.154:13000") }, CommandFlags.None);
  RedisValue[] values = redisDatabase.HashGet(key, fields, CommandFlags.None);
         foreach (var value in values)
                {
                   Console.WriteLine("The values of HashSet  :  \t" + value);
                    Console.WriteLine("\n");
                }

              redisConnection.Dispose();
            }
            catch (RedisTimeoutException ex)
            {
              
                Console.WriteLine("Timeout error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                
                Console.WriteLine("An error occurred: " + ex.Message);
            }
```

**Output:**

[image]